# How do I modify the lines in a etc/hosts?? Add # in the beginnig of the line which has specific domain?

Tags: text-processing, hosts

I have a host file which has about 15 lines of a specific host entry.

All these host entries has the text `# Entry added by Automation` in the entry.

For example:

```
10.122.123.124  file1.auto.test-json.abx.com    # Entry added by Automation
10.122.123.125  file2.auto.test-json.abx.com    # Entry added by Automation
10.122.123.126  file3.auto.test-json.abx.com    # Entry added by Automation
10.122.123.127  file4.auto.test-json.abx.com    # Entry added by Automation
```

I would want to either add a "#" in the beginning of the line which has `# Entry added by Automation` or delete the line completely.

Required output:

```
# 10.122.123.124  file1.auto.test-json.abx.com    # Entry added by Automation
# 10.122.123.125  file2.auto.test-json.abx.com    # Entry added by Automation
# 10.122.123.126  file3.auto.test-json.abx.com    # Entry added by Automation
# 10.122.123.127  file4.auto.test-json.abx.com    # Entry added by Automation
```

Comment: It wouldn't have taken terribly long to have edited the file to add 15 comment markers. Sometimes an automated fix is not the right solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can do with sed

It checks for lines including "Entry added by Automation" and then replace the beginning of lines with #

```
sed '/Entry added by Automation/ s/^/# /' -i /etc/hosts
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to filter out all lines that have that, you can use 'grep' with the -'v' option.  For example:

```
grep -v "# Entry added by Automation" /etc/hosts > /etc/hosts.new
mv /etc/hosts.new /etc/hosts
```